# Perl How to access a hash that is the element of an array that is the value of another hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I am trying to create a Hash that has as its value an array.

The first element of the value(which is an array) is a scalar.
The second element of the value(which is an array) is another hash.

I have put values in the key and value of this hash as follows :

```
${${$senseInformationHash{$sense}[1]}{$word}}++;
```

Here,

My main hash -> senseInformationHash

My Value -> Is an Array

So, `${$senseInformationHash{$sense}[1]}` gives me reference to my hash

and I put in key and value as follows :

```
${${$senseInformationHash{$sense}[1]}{$word}}++;
```

I am not sure if this is a correct way to do it. Since I am stuck and not sure how I can print this complex thing out. I want to print it out in order to check if I am doing it correctly.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The relevant FM to R is the the Perl Data Structures Cookbook.  You can get it by running `perldoc perldsc` in a terminal or go to http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html in your browser.  The article has examples of working with many different types of mixed data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write

```
$sense_information_hash{$sense}[1]{$word}++;
```

and be done with it.

Perl gets jealous of CamelCase, you know, so you should use proper underscores. Otherwise it can spit and buck and generally misbehave.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to access it after storing it this way ?

Comment: @Radz: `printf "value of %s is %d\n", $word, $sense_information_hash{$sense}[1]{$word};`

Comment: @Radz: that *is* the way to access it. You're giving it a path to the data and saying "whatever is there, increment the count".

Answer (score 2):

A hash value is never an array, it is an array reference.

To see if you are doing it right, you can dump out the whole structure:

```
my %senseInformationHash;
my $sense = 'abc';
my $word = '123';
${${$senseInformationHash{$sense}[1]}{$word}}++;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper( \%senseInformationHash );
```

which gets you:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'abc' => [
                 undef,
                 {
                   '123' => \1
                 }
               ]
    };
```

Note the `\1`: presumably you want the value to be 1, not a reference to the scalar 1.  You are getting the latter because your `${ ... }++;` says treat what's in the curly braces as a scalar reference and increment the scalar referred to.

`${$senseInformationHash{$sense}[1]}{$word}++;` does what you want, as does `$senseInformationHash{$sense}[1]{$word}++`.  You may find http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference helpful in seeing why.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Axeman and TChrist.

The code I have to access it is as follows :

```
    foreach my $outerKey (keys(%sense_information_hash))
{
  print "\nKey => $outerKey\n";
  print "  Count(sense) => $sense_information_hash{$outerKey}[0]\n";

        foreach(keys (%{$sense_information_hash{$outerKey}[1]}) )
    {
        print " Word wt sense => $_\n";
        print " Count  => $sense_information_hash{$outerKey}[1]{$_}\n"; 
    }
}
```

This is working now. Thanks much!